# Trigger ng-show when model is updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

**Objective**

I have to show or hide fields when user choose values from a list. On the followed sample I'm trying to simulate what I would like to do,

I would like to show the input text field only when the car colour is set it to Red :

**Code:**

Each time that user choose an option , I'm setting their properties on the controller

```
 $scope.CarModel.Colour = "Red";
```

That's fine, but I don't know how to trigger ng-show="CarCtrl.ValidateColour(CarModel.Colour) once the model is updated, in order to hide or show the field.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="carColour" ng-model="CarModel.Colour"  ng-show="CarCtrl.ValidateColour(CarModel.Colour)">
```

Comment: ng-show="CarModel.Colour" this will take the updated value of Colour as it is a scope property

Comment: `ng-show="CarModel.Colour === 'Red'"` -- will display the input only when the model is red.
You don't have to trigger ng-show manually... it will be processed automatically.

Comment: Hi Vinay, yes, you are right, but I don't want to have the 'Red' value on the view, that's why I'm calling a controller and then doing some operations there

Comment: You should avoid using functions when evaluating angular attributes such as `ng-show` as it can cause performance problems with large controllers / amount of watchers etc...

Answer (score 0):

What I usually like to do is have a little helper function for my ng-shows, for example...

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="CarModel.Colour" ng-show="showThis()">
```

JS:

```
$scope.showThis = function () {
    if(CarModel.Colour == 'red') return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look to this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2238g585/)**
you can call ValidateColour() function without "CarCtrl." since it is in scope

```
function CarCtrl($scope) {
$scope.ValidateColour = function(colour){
    return colour === "Red";
}
```

}